# C++: Header issues

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I just *can't* win with headers it seems.

I have a class `Log` of which has a header Log.h that defines the class `Log`, and then the Log.cpp implements the methods of `Log`. I need it available in Main.cpp, so I include Log.h into Main.cpp and I receive the notorious "already defined" errors.

If I take out the header from Main.cpp, I can't use the class.
If I take out the header from Log.cpp, then Log is (obviously) not defined.

I can't win here! What do I do?

**EDIT** YES, of course I have include guards.

```
#ifndef LOG_H_
#define LOG_H_

namespace vexal {

#define CCOL_RESET  "^[[0m"
#define CCOL_RED    "^[[31m"

class Log {
public:
    Log();
    virtual ~Log();
    static void genInstance();
private:
    static Log* _inst;
};

}

#endif /* LOG_H_ */
```

Then the includes are merely `#include "Log.h"` in both Log.cpp and Main.cpp.

Comment: What exactly are you including? Did you make sure your header only containers declarations rather than definitions? Can you post a small example showing your source?

Comment: Can you also show exactly what errors you're getting?

Comment: With the declarations you posted I don't see why you would duplicate declarations. Also, are the error messages you get compile-time or link-time messages? If they are compile-time is there anything like `vexal::Log` in your main.cpp?

Comment: Make smallest possible log.h/log.cpp/main.cpp files you can reproduce problem with and then post them here. Also show the way you compile it. You will get your answer super fast.

Comment: If you're using visual studio, the full error message we need is NOT in the error window, it is in the "output" window.

Comment: Are you by any chance using vexal::CCOL_RESET or vexal::CCOL_RED by mistake anywhere? Judging from where you put your macro definitions, I was thinking you could have use them in that manner somewhere in your .cpp files, which is wrong because macros do not work with namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being the order of which the includes were included. Some includes have to be included before others to avoid redefinition issues.

Answer (score 3):

Have you included include guards?

### Log.h

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H

// your code here

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might not have include guards?  Try adding to the top of your header file:

```
    #ifndef LOG_HEADER_FILE
    #define LOG_HEADER_FILE
```

And then at the bottom of your header file:

```
    #endif
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with two underscores are reserved by the implementation.  You probably want to choose a different name.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.  It's a bad habit of mine that unfortunately sticks around...

Answer (score -1):

This is rather vague, but most likely you need some include guards in your header. If you're using MSVC, a `#pragma once` up the top should do. If not, something standard like:

```
 #ifndef LOG_H_ 
 #define LOG_H_

 ///Rest of header file


 #endif
```